# How can I copy a text label using a button?

Tags: swift, macos

I would like to have a button that once selected, copies the text from the "textLabel20" label.

I have tried this, but it doesn't work and displays the following error:

> Cannot find 'UIPasteboard' in scope

Here is the code I am using that links to the action segue of the copy button I am using.

```
 @IBAction func copyTitleSelected(_ sender: Any) {
    
    UIPasteboard.general.string = textLabel20.text
    
 }
```

Comment: It's `NSPasteboard` if you are using AppKit

Comment: Thanks, so I can just swap out UIPasteboard with NSPasteboard and it should work straight away? Or are there any other modifications I will need to make?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by importing AppKit and updating the code to the below:

```
@IBAction func copyTitleSelected(_ sender: Any) {
let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
    pasteboard.clearContents()
    pasteboard.setString(textLabel20.stringValue, forType: .string)
}
```